# MySql Always return records in select statement

Tags: mysql

Hello im working with leftjoin in Mysql and im looking a way for return records for example i have it,

```
SELECT table1.value
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON `table1`.`id`=`table2`.`id`
where `table1`.`id`='this value no exist'
```

this return nothing, but i want a null or "" ,

like it

```
+--------+
| table1 |
+--------+
| null   |
+--------+
|        |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use aggregation to get one row with all possible values.  If there are none, then the value is `NULL`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table1.value)
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table2
     ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`
where `table1`.`id` = 'this value no exist';
```

If you are expecting only one value, then this will always return one row either with that value or `NULL`.

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is utterly useless in this query, unless you are looking for duplicate matches (which I doubt).  It is used neither for filtering nor for fetching columns.

Because the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` isn't needed, you can also do what you want as:

```
SELECT table1.value
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = 'this value no exist'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = 'this value no exist');
```

Note that the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is superfluous in your query.

Comment: i put only 1 value for example :P really i expect rows in both tables

Comment: is possible put a 0 replacing to null?

Comment: @jearca . . . Yes, just make it a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregate function, such as `MAX`:

```
SELECT MAX(table1.value)
...etc.
```

This is guaranteed to return exactly 1 row always.